# Custom y-axis labels does not show in ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have the following data:

```
dat <- structure(list(sn = c("K", "J", "I", "H", "G", "F", "E", "D", 
"C", "B", "A"), Station = c("Casiguran", "Baler", "Infanta", 
"Daet", "Virac", "Legazpi", "Catarman", "Borongan", "Guiuan", 
"Surigao", "Hinatuan"), Jan = c(278.8842105, 199.5590909, 357.0324324, 
279.5358974, 254.7305556, 321.9666667, 495.3512821, 658.6444444, 
467.2666667, 680.6545455, 810.8526316), Feb = c(238.8684211, 
163.1, 250.8945946, 200.7666667, 150.1108108, 272.7769231, 289.9205128, 
377.495, 314.147619, 443.1151515, 560.4289474), Mar = c(220.35, 
197.95, 201.7027027, 174.0102564, 156.3972973, 248.3692308, 274.7947368, 
383.82, 284.0857143, 360.6151515, 441.5605263), Apr = c(175.0684211, 
243.4363636, 190.5297297, 124.2692308, 141.9486486, 164.1128205, 
144.7794872, 217.78, 154.9809524, 219.4787879, 318.7578947), 
    May = c(227.7131579, 322.0909091, 197.6378378, 145.5128205, 
    153.7540541, 176.5820513, 153.6307692, 198.1666667, 613.8714286, 
    133.1636364, 263.5864865), Jun = c(223.2868421, 261.9272727, 
    245.2763158, 184.0578947, 222.9472222, 243.5589744, 212.3307692, 
    273.155, 215.347619, 152.2393939, 275.6948718), Jul = c(278.0868421, 
    272.4136364, 271.8026316, 254.5051282, 252.6, 283.2846154, 
    228.2230769, 241.3210526, 723.0714286, 165.1939394, 238.6315789
    ), Aug = c(201.7710526, 208.3181818, 191.4526316, 169.4289474, 
    155.9027027, 220.5820513, 167.7769231, 140.0388889, 160.8761905, 
    142.1848485, 193.6157895), Sep = c(271.9236842, 273.0136364, 
    270.3710526, 266.0051282, 250.7108108, 285.6615385, 209.7205128, 
    188.9052632, 188.0619048, 175.2181818, 214.8179487), Oct = c(533.0527778, 
    531.25, 626.0315789, 491.7871795, 397.0513514, 341.5897436, 
    333.0589744, 308.9277778, 290.3571429, 254.5212121, 283.1131579
    ), Nov = c(587.1527778, 371.6809524, 589.4216216, 528.8974359, 
    448.2722222, 467.9692308, 510.1947368, 536.835, 394.8190476, 
    481.18125, 450.1358974), Dec = c(518.4527778, 324.8590909, 
    694.1138889, 589.5157895, 445.46, 531.2263158, 628.0692308, 
    760.1736842, 564.2526316, 531.0066667, 579.9194444)), class = "data.frame", row.names =     
c(NA, -11L))
```

I am plotting a heatmap using the geom_tile() for this data. The script is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(viridis)

dat<-read.csv("monthly_sum.csv",header=T)
dat2<-melt(dat)
p<-ggplot(dat2,aes(variable,sn,fill=value))
p<-p + geom_tile()

p <- p + theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
         plot.margin = margin(1,0.5,0.5,0.5, "cm"),
         panel.border=element_rect(colour="black",fill=NA,size=1),
         axis.line.x=element_line(colour="black"),
         axis.line.y=element_line(colour="black"),
         axis.text=element_text(size=20,colour="black",family="sans"),
         axis.title=element_text(size=20,colour="black",family="sans"),
         legend.position = "", legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'white'))

p <- p + scale_color_viridis(discrete=FALSE,option='D',direction=-1)
p <- p + scale_fill_viridis(discrete=FALSE,direction=-1)

p <- p + scale_y_discrete(breaks=c(seq(1,11,1)),labels=c("Caiguran","Baler","Infanta","Daet","Virac","Legazpi","Catarman","Borongan","Guiuan","Surigao","Hinatuan"),expand=c(0,0))
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
p <- p + labs(x = "Month", y = "Station")


ggsave("test.pdf",plot=p,width=10,height=8)
```

Here's the output:

[image: Output]

Problem:

(a) When I specify the labels for the y-axis, they dont show up in the output plot.

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

I'll appreciate any help!!

Comment: Maybe this is usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287272/put-the-y-axis-on-the-left-of-a-heatmap

Comment: Since the y-axis is discrete, the `breaks` argument shouldn't be numeric but something akin to `unique(dat2$sn)`.

Comment: @teunbrand OMG!!!! that solved it! Thanks!!